# Refreshing values on fields

Tags: google-app-maker

I have multiple pages in my applications, one of them is to add a driver information.

When i go to add driver information page and fill some of the fields like "driver licence" text box, then i do not add this to DB and click "go back" button (that discard the changes and come back to home page) when i enter again to this page the fields that i have previously filled in with data do not clear and refresh (its supposed to all fields be clear and empty)

Does anyone have a solution for that?

code for "go back button:

```javascript
app.datasources.driver.clearChanges(function() {
    console.log("cleared changes");
});
returnToDriver();
```

returnToDriver() code is:

```javascript
app.datasources.DRIVERS_LIST.query.clearFilters();
app.datasources.DRIVERS_LIST.load();
app.showPage(app.pages.Driver);
```

Already tried:

```javascript
widget.root.descendants.TextBox1.value = "";
widget.root.descendants.TextBox1.value  = null;
```

but do not work for me.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Potentially there are can be multiple ways to leave the page:

- browser navigation including navigation hotkeys
- links on the page that can navigate to other pages
- in-app navigation buttons/hotkeys
- etc...

The best way to handle all possible navigation scenarios is using `onDetach` page event

```javascript
// Implicit way
// page onDetach event handler, assuming that page
// is bound to appropriate datasource:
// @datasources.<MyDatasource>.modes.create
widget.datasource.clearChanges();

// Explicit way
// Explicitly clearing changes for create datasources in
// page onDetach event handler
app.datasources.<MyDatasource1>.modes.create.clearChanges();
app.datasources.<MyDatasource2>.modes.create.clearChanges();
...
```

Once you add this code to the `onDetach` page's event handler you can remove all other `clearChanges` occurrences from the page.

Comment: Hello Pavel,

Probably i did not express myself the best way.
The problem is that i have multiple text boxes in the page that do not clear when i press "Go Back" Button.

Scenario 1:
go to add driver page and fill text box 1, then i press "go back" and navigate to other page. When i enter add driver page again, text box 1 is with the same value that i enter the first time i enter add driver page. When i press "go back" i need to clear the text in text box 1 for the next time i enter that text box is empty.

Comment: If the widget is bound to the right field, it should be cleared. Try to change form's datasource to `Inherited` and page's datasource to `@datasources.<MyDatasource>.modes.create`

Comment: Hello Pavel, can not try that. This page has 3 different datasources. I have 3 panels, where fields are bounded to each panel datasource field.
In my "go back" button i'm clearing all 3 datasources but the fields are not clear.

Comment: @JingleBells, I've updated my answer to handle your case.

Comment: It worked for text boxes. Only problem now is to clean one label that is widget.root.descendants.DrivePicker8.selectedDocName

Is there any solution for that?

PS: your rock on this.

Comment: Hm... `Drive Pricker`'s property won't clear... In case you need this property value, I recommend to bind it to some draft record's field `@datasource.item.DocName`, and then bind this field to a `Label`. `clearChanges()` will clear both field and `Label`, however `Drive Pricker`'s property will persist the value, but end user will never see it.